# LESS: Retrieve and use wildcard value in style definition

Tags: css, less

I have classes called .col-[1-24], e.g., .col-1, .col-2, .col-3 etc.

I want to achieve the following:

```
.col-$varname {
  width: @varname
}
```

... where @varname is a LESS variable and $varname, conceptually, is a variable selector whose value will be passed to @varname.

Another way of putting it is that any .col-X should have a width of @col-X.

Is this possible with LESS, or if not, with CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure can (updated to allow flexible units and flexible property value [LESS 1.6]):

**LESS**

```
.makeIndexProp(@max, @class-prefix, @unit: px, @prop: width,  @i:1) when (@i <= @max) {
  .@{class-prefix}@{i} {
    @{prop}: unit(@i, @unit);
  }
  .makeIndexProp(@max, @class-prefix, @i:(@i+1));
}

.makeIndexProp(5, col-);
```

**CSS Output**

```
.col-1 {
  width: 1px;
}
.col-2 {
  width: 2px;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 3px;
}
.col-4 {
  width: 4px;
}
.col-5 {
  width: 5px;
}
```